# local file reference xcode 7 swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to read data from a text file, when I try loading the file via an absolute url which points to the file onto my desktop the content loads

```
 file = "/Users/melwyn.p/Desktop/data.txt"
 text = try String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But if I change the file path to refer to the data.txt file dragged into the project folder it is unable to find the file, get the following error

"The file “data.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

```
 file = "data.txt"
 text = try String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I change the file path to refer to the data.txt file dragged into the project folder

The path you want is the path of the *data.txt* file built into the app. You do not know what it is; you must ask the runtime. Call NSBundle's `mainBundle` to get the app bundle, and call its `pathForResource:ofType:` to get the file's path.

Comment: The following code worked
file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "txt")!

Comment: That's it exactly.